# running commands on remote server single quote confusion! (shell)

Tags: shell, remote-server

I am doing a script where the user controls what commands to be run on a remote server

For example

```
sshpass -p myPassword ssh -q root@127.0.0.1 ''$myCommand''
```

the user defines `$myCommand`. However, What if the user's command has single quotes!!! It will get mixed with the ones that I have put. Let's say the user's command is

```
echo 'this is a the remote server `hostname`'
```

Is there a way to solve this....?

Answer (score 1):

In the example case that you give, it doesn't seem to matter.  With other types of quote combinations odd things do happen

```
$ hostname
laptop1
$ ssh remotehost1 echo 'this is the remote `hostname`'
this is the remote remotehost1
$ ssh remotehost1 echo "this is the remote `hostname`"
this is the remote laptop1
$ ssh remotehost1 echo 'this is the remote \`hostname\`'
this is the remote `hostname`
```

And here is a worse example!

```
$ ssh remotehost1 ls -l *.txt
ls: cannot access config.txt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access examples.txt: No such file or directory
```

What has happened in the above example is that the *.txt has been evaluated before the command is sent to the remote.  It finds local files called config.txt and examples.txt locally but listing them on the remote fails!

The solution in this case (and in most cases) is to surround the entire command with single quotes.  I believe that this is the decision you have made in your system.

```
$ ssh remotehost1 'ls -l *.txt'
-rw-r--r-- 1 beaker muppet 15326 2013-03-20 19:08 gs.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 beaker muppet 30781 2013-05-14 02:07 out.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 beaker muppet 53567 2013-06-11 18:24 pip-log.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 beaker muppet  2961 2013-06-28 19:41 plug.txt
```

If you wish to do this AND include single quotes in the command then it works, some of the time

```
ssh remotehost1 'ls -l 'gs.txt''
-rw-r--r-- 1 beaker muppet 15326 2013-03-20 19:08 gs.txt
```

One case where this does not work is this

```
$ ssh remotehost1 'echo 'this is the remote `hostname`''
this is the remote laptop1
```

What is happening here is fairly odd.  `'echo '` is treated as a string in a pair of quotes.   ```` this is the remote `hostname``` is treated as an unquoted string and finally ````''`` is treated as a pair of quotes with nothing in them.  So the backticks around the hostname command lead it to be evaluated before the ssh command is sent

To solve this problem ( particularly as the commands are running as root ) I would reject any input with any single quotes in

For running more complicated remote commands something like fabric http://docs.fabfile.org might be better

Answer (score -1):

```
myCommand=$'echo \'this is the remote server $(hostname)\''
sshpass -p myPassword ssh -q root@127.0.0.1 "$myCommand"
```

Whatever the value of `myCommand` is (even if it contains double quotes itself) is passed to the remote server.

With `''$myCommand''`, you are just concatenating the empty string with the first and last words resulting from the expansion of `myCommand`.

Comment: Double quotes transform  the variable then passes it to the remote server. So it gets translated locally !!! That was not my question

Comment: But nothing *in* `myCommand` is expanded. The exact contents of `myCommand` are sent to the remote host, where the string `echo 'this is a the remote server \`hostname\`'` is expanded as desired.